# Need Resolution :Question on workflow rules

Tags: workflow, workflowrule

Please help me with the below resolution:

There are two workflows Q1 & Q2 & Two Fields A1 & B1

--->>>>When **Q1** is executed Field **A1** is updated to 10 & **B1** is updated to 20

----->>>>When **Q1** is executed Field **A1** is updated to 20 & **B1** is updated to 10

What is the final outcome of **A1** & **B1**

Comment: your question is incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A1 and B1 will be one of these four possible values:

```
A1 | B1
---+---
10 | 10
10 | 20
20 | 10
20 | 20
```

We can't know in advance which result will occur, because it depends on the order in which the field updates are applied; the behavior is explicitly undefined in the documentation, so you can make no assumptions. If you need a deterministic order, always use the Process Builder, which is more reliable in terms of the order of operations.